# Understanding syntax of expression >>> new = [int(i) for i in old.split(' ')]

Tags: python, type-conversion, list-comprehension

I'm a bit confused with the following code, in terms of combining both list comprehension and type conversion.

```
# Statement 1
list1 = input('enter 10 integers separated by spaces: ')
# type(list1) --> str

# Statement 2
list2 = [int(i) for i in list1.split(' ')]
# type(list2) --> lst
```

If I were trying to do the above, I would have used two steps.
(1) list1.split()
(2) loop through the list of strings to convert them into integers

Could someone explain in a bit more detail how Python 3.6 interprets statement two? How does Python know to first split the string apart and THEN make the pieces integers? As one example, why would you not write it like this?

```
 # Statement 2
list2 = [i for int(i) in list1.split(' ')]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`result = [f(x) for x in sequence]` can be perceived as a short form of the following:

```
result = []
for x in sequence:  # for each element: take it, name it x and do the following
    result.append(f(x))
```

(Strictly speaking, these forms may behave differently if some call of `f(x)` raises an exception.)

So in your case the value of `list1.split(' ')` (`sequence`) is evaluated, then each element is processed.

`[i for int(i) ...]` is not possible since `int(i)` can't be a name.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the for-loop syntax works like this:

```
for VAR in ITERABLE:
    # Do stuff with VAR.
```

Note that VAR is just a variable name. It is not allowed to be an expression
like `int(VAR)`.

List comprehension syntax follows similar rules:

```
xs = [EXPRESSION for VAR in INTERABLE]
```

Again, VAR is allowed to be a variable name, not a full expression.
The ultimate list (`xs`) will be wheverer EXPRESSION evalates to
for every item in ITERABLE.

It's not clear that your alternative Statement 2 would be very
useful. Consider:

```
# Alternative Statement 2.
list2 = [i for int(i) in list1.split(' ')]

# More generically.
list2 = [EXPRESSION2 for EXPRESSION1 in ITERABLE]
```

In this scenario, how would a programmer refer to the value of EXPRESSION1 if
she wanted to use that value as part of EXPRESSION2? You need a name for that
value so you can do stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the list comprehension in your code is syntactically incorrect:

```
>>> list2 = [i for int(i) in list1.split(' ')]
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
>>>
```

The correct form is `[int(i) for i in list1.split(' ')]`. I'm going to assume you meant the latter throughout the rest of the answer.

> Could someone explain in a bit more detail how Python 3.6 interprets statement two?

The list comprehension:

```
list2 = [int(i) for i in list1.split(' ')]
```

Is equivalent (in terms of functionality) to the for loop:

```
list2 = []
for i in list1.split(' '):
    list2.append(int(i))
```

> How does Python know to first split the string apart and THEN make the pieces integers? As one example, why would you not write it like this?

Python knows how to execute the list comprehension because it knows each part of the comprehension, and is able to execute each one in the correct order. What may help clear some confusion is to view the byte-code generated by the list comprehension. Viewing the byte-code essential lets us see each step the Python interpreter takes in executing your code:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f1ebce63390, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (list1)
              8 LOAD_ATTR                1 (split)
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (' ')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 GET_ITER
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 STORE_NAME               2 (list2)
             20 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an excellent feature called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which can be used to write code that behaves like immutables. (It's so convenient that I almost tend to overuse it.)

```
>>> [s for s in 'abcd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> [s.strip() for s in ('a  ', ' b ', '   c\n')]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [s+' under' for s in 'something over here'.split()]
['something under', 'over under', 'here under']
```

In your case there is a type conversion going on, similar to this:

```
>>> [float(s) for s in '1 2 4.5'.split()]
[1.0, 2.0, 4.5]
```

You can also use this for walking through any iterable, such as a range:

```
>>> [random.random()*i/2 for i in range(3)]
[0.0, 0.21324127757409878, 0.9616595926178124]
```

List comprehension also supports if statements (something I haven't seen in any other language, but I don't know too many), which makes it even more powerful:

```
>>> [n+' here' for n in 'joe bob elsie jane'.split() if 'o' not in n]
['elsie here', 'jane here']
```

The above is more performant, but otherwise the equivalent of:

```
>>> s = 'joe bob elsie jane'
>>> l = s.split()
>>> r = []
>>> for n in l:
...     if 'o' not in n:
...             r.append(n+' here')
...
>>> r
['elsie here', 'jane here']
```

... which kinda makes you realize what they're for. In the same manner you can wrap `for` loops too:

```
>>> ['o'*x+'h' for x in range(1,5) for y in range(2)]
['oh', 'oh', 'ooh', 'ooh', 'oooh', 'oooh', 'ooooh', 'ooooh']
```

And then you can of course nest list comprehensions so you can write your whole program in one line. Mad, but fun.

```
>>> [print(s) for s in ['X'*(10-j)+'-'*j for j in [random.randint(2,7) for _ in range(6)]]]
XXXXXXX---
XXXXXXX---
XXXXXXXX--
XXXXXXX---
XXX-------
XXXXXXXX--
```